# If $X$ is a Random Variable, finding a $Y$ for which $\mathbb{P}(\vert X-Y\vert >\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega ,F,\mathbb{P})$ where $F=\sigma(A)$ for some algebra $A$. For any bounded random variable $X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ I am trying to prove that there exists a simple function $Y=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\chi_{A_i}$ where $A_i\in A$ such that $\mathbb{P}(\vert X-Y\vert >\varepsilon)<\varepsilon$.

I have an approach in mind, but I am not sure if my sets $A_n$ belong to the algebra in question.

By simple approximation I know that there is a sequence $X_n$ of sets that converge to $X$ uniformly. We can define $X_n$ by $T_n(X)$ where $T_n(x)=n\chi_{x>n}+\sum_{k=0}^{n2^n-1}k2^{-n}\chi_{(k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n})}$. However, I don't see what these sets in the indicator functions have to do with the algebra $A$ since $A$ may not even contain subsets of real numbers.

How can I find $Y$ such that the sets $A_i$ actually belong to the algebra $A$? Is there a way to proceed that doesn't use simple approximation?

Comment: Any reason to use X for both the sample space and the random variable ? It seems like a typo.

Comment: Oops will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\cal K$ be the algebra of simple $A$-measurable random variables, and $\cal H$ be the closure of $\cal K$ in the Ky Fan metric: $$d(X,Y)=\inf(\varepsilon>0: P(|X-Y|>\varepsilon)<\varepsilon).$$ Then $\cal K\subseteq H$ and $\cal H$ satisfies the conditions of the [functional monotone class theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_functions), so $\cal H$ contains all bounded $F$-measurable random variables.